# Clion with MinGW not compiling simple Hello World app

Tags: gcc, mingw, clion

I have trouble in compiling a simple hello world application with CLion and MinGW. The buttons for Run and Debug are grayd out.

I have installed MinGW with mingw32-gcc-g++ and mingw32-make packages. 
[image: mingw32-gcc-g++]

After that I have install CLion which detected automatically the right folder for MinGW. However make, c compiler and c++ compiler will not get the checkmark.

[image: ToolChain]

Also in CMakeError.log file found the following:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
1


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa

The output was:
1


Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
1


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/Users/Tau/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/94853116/94853116/__default__0/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe "cmTryCompileExec3424130643/fast"
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec3424130643.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3424130643.dir/build

mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Users/Tau/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/94853116/94853116/__default__0/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 138.2344.17\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report D:\Users\Tau\.clion10\system\cmake\generated\94853116\94853116\__default__0\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CMakeFiles 1

Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3424130643.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec3424130643.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c D:\Users\Tau\.clion10\system\cmake\generated\94853116\94853116\__default__0\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c

CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec3424130643.dir\build.make:56: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3424130643.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed

mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Users/Tau/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/94853116/94853116/__default__0/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3424130643.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1

Makefile:113: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec3424130643/fast' failed

mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTryCompileExec3424130643/fast] Error 2
```

I am unable to figure out. I have tried also with cygwin x64 and the same issue occurs. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much time spent without any clue, I found that actually the crashing softwares were cc1.exe and cc1plus.exe. After using Dependency Waker tool which led mo to manually adding the zlib1.dll file near these two crashing exe, I found that the real reason was that package mingw32-libz was not installed. 
I have installed mingw32-libz package in MinGW and removed manually added dlls and I get all checkmarks in settings.